# What is the __CHECKFIX1436934 environment variable?

Tags: bash

On OS X 10.9.5 my bash shell has the following environment variable set:

__CHECKFIX1436934=1

What is the purpose of this value? I am surprised there is no record of anybody asking this before.

Comment: See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5559451, no answer there either. Interesting...

Comment: I have `__CHECKFIX1436934=1` in my ENV too. I note that the few search results that I find for this include it as part of  programmers asking for help and listing their ENV related  to the Go language, Python, SublimeText or Brew. I have all of these installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes from launch services, specifically this binary

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
```

and that environment variable seems to be inherited by many processes, as you can see with `ps -Efax`

1436934 looks like the number of digits in recent Apple "radar" bug numbers, so perhaps it refers to some value used internally for testing.